# Can I create custom email templates in Tempo

Tags: jira

Is it possible to edit or create tempo email templates? Mainly as a workaround for this issue https://tempoplugin.jira.com/browse/TT-452

Could not find tempo email templates in a similar place as there are jira email templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current version of Tempo Timesheets, it is not possible to edit the Planning or Timesheet approval mails. I do not have information about a date/verion when the above mentioned improvement will be released.
The only mail that can be edited is the mail sent by the Tempo Scheduler (https://tempoplugin.jira.com/wiki/display/TEMPO0714/Scheduler+E-mail+Template )

See [source](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/30933052/tempo-custom-email-templates).